# Android getter and setter usage in different files?

Tags: java, android

I have a getter and setter method in java

```
public class TempInfo {

  private int user_ID;

  public int getID() {
    return user_ID;
  }

  public void setID(int id) {
    this.user_ID = id;
  }
}
```

an I have 2 different class. In the first I call the setter method and it sets the parameter because if I call the getter method from there it displays the value of the "user_ID" but if I call the getter method in the second class it displays 0.

First class (I use setter here)

```
String segment = response.substring(response.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
TempInfo i = new TempInfo();
i.setID(Integer.parseInt(segment));
```

The "segment" is return successfully with my id from database.
Second class (I want to use the getter)

```
TempInfo i = new TempInfo();
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" +i.getID(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Overall, I want to set the "user_ID" in a class, store there and display in a another class. I tore the ID in database but i also need the ID in java.

Comment: You have to use the same instance where you set the value.

Comment: Are you saying you want to store the `user_ID` in a database?  Have you used SQLite before?

Comment: I store the id in mysql and I get the ID with php and sendrequest in java.

Comment: If you mean the "TempInfo i = new TempInfo()" that is same in the two class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making two objects of TempInfo.
Lets call them TempInfo1 and TempInfo2.
In first activity, you did

```
TEmpInfo1.setID(Integer.parseInt(segment));
```

and in next activity, you are calling

```
TEmpInfo2.getID();
```

One possible solution of this is that you can use Singleton.

```
public class TempInfo {

private TempInfo() {
}

static TempInfo tempInfo;
private static int user_ID;

public static TempInfo getInstance() {
    if (tempInfo == null) {
        tempInfo = new TempInfo();
    }
    return tempInfo;
}

public int getID() {
    return user_ID;
}

public void setID(int id) {
    this.user_ID = id;
}
```

}

And use

```
TempInfo.getInstance().setId(Integer.parseInt(segment));
TempInfo.getInstance().getId();
```

After this changes, your code should work.

Comment: When I use the getInstance() ?

Comment: @M4ST3RX, I had edit my answer please go through it.

Comment: I wrote it but Android Studio says tha static not allowed to use at the getInstance

Comment: Oh sorry I did not refresh. I see now